# Bounding Box labeling for VOC data in SSD

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I used [SSD](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) for CNN training and I tested with VOC2007 and VOC2012 dataset.
I do not quite understand the normalized Bounding Box in the VOC2007 dataset.
Say for VOC2007 data set, when we look at Annotations/000002.xml file. It has the bounding box of

```
<size>
  <width>335</width>
  <height>500</height>
  <depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object><name>train</name>
<pose>Unspecified</pose>
<truncated>0</truncated>
<difficult>0</difficult>
<bndbox>
   <xmin>139</xmin>
   <ymin>200</ymin>
   <xmax>207</xmax>
   <ymax>301</ymax>
</bndbox></object>
```

That is ok to draw a bounding box to the image shown below.

But when I look at the normalized data at labels/000002.txt file.

```
18 0.516417910448 0.501 0.202985074627 0.202

How these 0.516417910448 0.501 0.202985074627 0.202 are related to 139 200 207 301?
```

I used 335 and 500 to normalize, but don't get these values.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right labels? 18 isn't even the class id of "train".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past, my solution was:

Consider you have (from your Pascal VOC XML file - Annotations/000002.xml):

```
width = 335
height = 500

xmin = 139
xmax = 207
ymin = 200
ymax = 301
```

To normalize the bounding box coords, you can do:

```
def norm_box(width, height, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
    x = (xmin + xmax)/2. * 1./width
    w = (xmax - xmin) * 1./width
    y = (ymin + ymax)/2. * 1./height
    h = (ymax - ymin) * 1./height
    return (x,y,w,h)

box_norm = norm_box(width, height, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
print(box_norm)
```

The output is:

```
(0.5164179104477612, 0.501, 0.20298507462686566, 0.202)
```

that matches the normalized data at labels/000002.txt file.

```
18 0.516417910448 0.501 0.202985074627 0.202
```

To denormalize it, you can do:

```
def denorm_box(width, height, x, y, w, h):
    xmax = int((x*width) + (w * width)/2.0)
    xmin = int((x*width) - (w * width)/2.0)
    ymax = int((y*height) + (h * height)/2.0)
    ymin = int((y*height) - (h * height)/2.0)
    return (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

(x,y,w,h) = box_norm
box = denorm_box(width, height, x, y, w, h)
print(box)
```

The output is:

```
(139, 207, 200, 301)
```

You can see a demo here: 
https://notebooks.azure.com/andrewssobral/libraries/utils/html/bbnorm.ipynb

Hope this help you